# Which latest solr version does django-haystack support?

Tags: django, search, solr, django-haystack

I am using **Django-Haystack** for implementing search functionality in my Django application. I use Solr backend search engine for Haystack.

I have the following questions related to search backend:

- What latest Solr version does Haystack support?
- Are there any alternatives which could be used instead of Solr?

Answer (score 2):

Haystack supports **6.x** [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) versions. Haystack supports [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch), [Whoosh](https://bitbucket.org/mchaput/whoosh/wiki/Home), [Xapian](https://xapian.org/) along with [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).